# Laggy file manipulations with Unity

Tags: unity, nautilus, performance

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 11.04/Unity, and every file manipulations just feel very laggy (at least one second):

- Selection
- Drag and drop
- Even folder browsing

My hard drive is OK, I'm using the proprietary ATI driver, everything runs fine in every other OS I have installed except Ubuntu since the upgrade.

Am I the only one seeing this ?

Comment: Just tried the CompizConfig tweaks + the manual ATI driver upgrade without noticeable change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FInally found the solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10795510&postcount=11), I had to delete the `gvfs-metadata` folder:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata
```

Comment: ... What exactly does it do...?

Comment: GVFS is "Gnome Virtual File System", apparently this metadata folder gets bloated after some time.